# Procesar petición POST con API Fetch

Tags: javascript, ajax, ecmascript-6

Estoy tratando de ingresar un registro a mi base de datos con PHP, usando la API Fetch para evitar que la página se recargue, de este modo

```
let button = document.getElementById("ingreso")

button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    let nuevoUsuario = document.getElementById("nombre").value
    let newUser = {
        name: nuevoUsuario
    }
    fetch('alta.php', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(newUser)
    })
})
```

Como pueden ver

- Obtengo el button al cual le hago clic
- le agrego un `eventListener` para estar a la escucha de cuando le den click
- Por dentro obtengo el valor del input, donde el usuario escribe el nombre
- declaro un objeto que contiene en la `key` el valor asignado de la variable `nuevoUsuario`
- Con la API `fetch` paso la URL
- como segundo argumento paso el method que es POST y en la `key` body el valor del objeto que es `newUser`

Cuando presiono el botón, desde la consola del navegador, en la pestaña de **Netwrok** visualizo lo siguiente

```
Status Code: 200 OK
```

Y el payload es:

```
{name: "alfa"}
name: "alfa"
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Ya corregí el error anterior, era un detalle con el método prepare() sin embargo ahora aunque se procesa la consulta cuando hago un SELECT  en mi tabla, cada registro que intento dar de alta me aparece como `NULL`

Comment: Es mejor agregar explícitamente el tipo de dato que vas a enviar es este caso el `Content-Type`: `application/json`, dale un vistazo a este enlace aquí esta la información super entendible y completa: https://eldevsin.site/fetch-api-la-guia-completa-y-olvidarse-de-axios/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta indicar el `Content-type` en la petición:

```
fetch('alta.php', {
  method: 'post',
  body: JSON.stringify( newUser ),
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
} );
```

Adicionalmente, desde PHP **no** puedes obtener tus datos mediante la superglobal `$POST`, tienes que obtenerlos desde el *body*:

```
$params = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'php://input' ), true );
```

Comment: entiendo gracias por la recomendación y respuesta, en otra oportunidad si me lo permites te comparto algunos repositorios que tengo para que los juzgues, toma en cuenta que soy mayormente un aprendiz

Comment: A ver si te crees que yo soy experto o algo ... ¡ si es mas por *hobby* que por otra cosa ! :-D